# Django loop over list from view in html template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm asking how I can pick up a `for loop` in my django class based view to my HTML template.

User can check one or multiple checkboxe(s) and I would like to display informations for each checked checkboxes.

In my view I have :

```
checkbox_list = self.request.GET.getlist('PUBSDChoice') #Get object id checked by user
context_data['checkbox_list'] = checkbox_list

for checkbox in checkbox_list:
    pubsd = Publication.objects.get(id=checkbox)  
    get_request = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).count()

    context_data['pubsd'] = pubsd
    context_data['get_request'] = get_request
```

Now, in my template I have :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>{% trans 'Publication ID' %}</th>
        <th>{% trans 'Requests' %}</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in checkbox_list %} # I'm not sure for this loop
    <tr>
        <td>{{ pubsd.pub_id }}</td> #Do I have to add item.??
        <td>{{ get_request }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you very much

**EDIT :**

This is my real code with all querysets inside my view :

```
checkbox_list = self.request.GET.getlist('PUBSDChoice')
context_data['checkbox_list'] = checkbox_list

for checkbox in checkbox_list:
    pubsd = Publication.objects.get(id=checkbox)  # display publication id

    # Count number of requests in download table for checked publication
    get_request = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).count()
    #Get sum of publication usage (= downloads) for checked publication
    get_download = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).aggregate(get_sum_usage=Sum('usage'))

    # Get country which maximum download the checked publication
    get_country = Country.objects.filter(download__pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).annotate(
                ndown=Count('download')).order_by('-ndown').first()
    # Get customer which maximum download the checked publication
    get_customer = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).values('email').order_by(
                'email').annotate(count_email=Count('email')).first()
    # Get the best downloaded format for the checked publication
    get_format = Download.objects.filter(pub__publication__id=pubsd.id).values('pub__format').annotate(
                format_count=Count('pub__format')).order_by('-format_count').first()

    context_data['pubsd'] = pubsd
    context_data['get_request'] = get_request
    context_data['get_download'] = get_download
    context_data['get_country'] = get_country
    context_data['get_customer'] = get_customer['email']
    context_data['get_format'] = get_format['pub__format']
```

And this is exactly my model :

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    pub_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('publication ID'), default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('publication title'), null=False, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('category'), null=False, related_name='publication')
    nb_document = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('number of documents'), default=0)
    nb_download = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('number of downloads'), default=0)
    new_publication = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('new publication'), default=True)

class Document(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('language'), choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, null=False)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('format'), choices=FORMAT_CHOICES, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('document title'), null=False)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, verbose_name=_('publication title'), null=False,
                                    related_name='documents')
    nb_download = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('number of downloads'), default=0)

class Download(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('e-mail'), null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=_('country'), related_name='download')
    pub = models.ForeignKey(Document, verbose_name=_('Publication ID'), null=False)
    usage = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('usage'), default=0)

class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('e-mail'), null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=_('country'))
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('institution'), null=True)
```

As I said previously, for one checked publication it works fine, but when I want to check multiple publications, it does't work.

If someone could help me to convert this, it will be super ! Else I will try to use the good answer previously done to do that :)

Comment: Here you override the context keys in each iteration. But nevertheless, don't perform the queries in a `for` loop, use `.annotate(..)`.

Comment: You're right, but if user selects multiple checkboxes, I have to display some queryes for the first checked object, then the second one etc .. I have other queries with `.annotate` but not all in the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you each time overwrite the previous value of the key. As a result in the final `context_data` contains only values extracted in the *last* iteration.

```
checkbox_list = self.request.GET.getlist('PUBSDChoice')
context_data['checkbox_list'] = checkbox_list

context_data['pubsd'] = Publication.objects.filter(
    id__in=checkbox_list
).annotate(
    ndown=Count('publication__download')  # or something related
)
```

We thus filter the queryset such that it only contains `Publication`s with the `id` in the list, and we annotate with the number of downloads (It is possible that the expression is a bit different, since you did not include the `models.py`).

The above will *not* be sorted according to the `checkbox_list`. If that is a requirement, you can post-sort it.

In the template, you can then render this with:

```
{% for item in pubsd %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.pub_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.ndown }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

We thus iterate over the `pubsd` queryset, and for each `item` (this is a `Publication` object), we render `item.pub_id`, and `item.ndown`.

Comment: Nice explanation, now I have to see how I can handle your answer with my code. I could show you my entire querysets with models but it will be a bit hard because I have 7-8 different querysets.

Comment: @user10390326: do these querysets "interact". The fact that there are other qs, is usually not problematic.

Comment: Ok, I have to look how I can convert my qs with your code ! I will accept your answer when it will work ;)

Comment: I made something, maybe I should sent my new queries on Stackoverflow Code Review ? It seems to work, but honnestly I'm not sure that all is good. I valid your answer too ;)

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: Django 1.11.16 ;)

Comment: @user10390326: it is rather unfortnuate that in Django-1.11, there is no way to `filter` in the `Count(..)` I think this could really improve readability. I would consider upgrading :)

Comment: Oh ok ! Unfortunately I have no choice because my business uses Django 1.11 and not 2.x up to now :/ If I want a view between my old code and the new one, I have to create a new question on SO or I have to post this one in Code Review ?